# Schema access in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is view created in schema global like

```
CREATE VIEW global.reg_salesprod_v1 
AS
    SELECT 
        b.id, a.mat_num, c.style
    FROM
        global.tableA AS a 
    INNER JOIN
        rpo.tableb AS b ON a.id = b.id
    INNER JOIN
        rpt.tablec AS c ON a.id = c,id
```

So there are 3 schema - global, rpo, rpt

and the view is in the global schema.

Do I need to have access to all 3 schema - global, rpo, rpt
or only global schema, to access the view?

Please share your thoughts.
Thanks

Comment: global schema access is enough.

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: To access `global.reg_salesprod_v1`, you need access to the `global` schema only.

Comment: The key thing is ownership; if the objects you reference inside the `VIEW` all have the same owner, then you only need access to the `VIEW` ( not even the wholemof th `global` schema).